# Stripe CLI: 'stripe trigger' not sending event checkout.session.completed

Tags: stripe-payments

In the Stripe CLI version 1.13.0, I'm running `$ stripe trigger checkout.session.completed`

But I never get the event type 'checkout.session.completed', aka `req.event.type === 'checkout.session.completed'` in node.

Instead, Stripe sends events:

`'product.created'`

`'price.created'`

`'payment_intent.created'`

`'customer.created'`

`'payment_intent.requires_action'`

Stripe never sends `'checkout.session.completed'`.

Similarly
`stripe trigger charge.succeeded` only sends the event `charge.failed`

Comment: I tried to reproduce using Stripe CLI version 1.13.0 and it worked for me.  Can you update the question with the version of the CLI you're using (`stripe -v`) and try the latest version if you're using and older version?  If that doesn't work can you add `--log-level debug` to the `stripe listen` command, then trigger the Event, then update your question with the debug output from the listen command?

Comment: It's also 1.13.0.  I'm not sure what I should be looking for in the logs. Another weird similar issue,  `stripe trigger charge.succeeded` only sends `charge.failed` with a card_declined code.

Comment: It's hard to say what to look for in the logs because we can't see them.  Can you update your question to include the debug log output?

Comment: I figured it out. will post the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the payments tab in test mode and found the answer there. The payments were being blocked for not verifying with 3DS. I lowered 3DS settings in my fraud rules and disabled a block rule for `Block if !:has_liability_shift:`.

Comment: hmm there is no such setting + when using stripe CLI these rules seems like not trigged.. Any other idea how to solve it?