# Using Stripe CLI with checkout.session.completed

Tags: stripe-payments

I am banging my head and looking for information how to finish simple trigger "checkout.session.completed". After I am triggering it I am getting: payment_intent.requires_action instead of just "checkout.session.completed" as documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test.

I am banging my head looking for an information how to solve it but there is 0 information that i can find. I came up with something liek this:

```
stripe trigger checkout.session.completed --add payment_intent:confirm=true
```

or

```
stripe trigger checkout.session.completed --override payment_intent:status=succeeded
```

but it does not help. I am sure that i need to add something here but it has to be documented! :(

Can you please help?

p.s. this solution also did not helped: [Stripe CLI: 'stripe trigger' not sending event checkout.session.completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310412/stripe-cli-stripe-trigger-not-sending-event-checkout-session-completed)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, this looks like a bug on Stripe's end. I'd recommend reaching out to their support team: https://support.stripe.com/contact and circling back once it's been fixed

Comment: Quick update: it seems Stripe just fixed it as the Event works as expected now.

Comment: Fixed where? should i update CLI? which command works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Stripehas fixed because it was a bug